# Why GIT Fetch failed from IntelliJ and works from cygwin shell

Tags: git, intellij-idea, cygwin

I am using git with cygwin. Fetching and cloning remote repo works from cygwin shell. But fails from IntellJ IDEA with message:

> Fetch failed: fatal: unpack-objects failed

When try execute `git pull` from cygwin it works, but from IntelliJ fails with error:

> fatal: 'pull' appears to be a git command, but we were not

Any idea how to solve it?

Here is my git config:

```
core.autocrlf=true  
user.name=MyUser  
user.email=my@email.com  
core.repositoryformatversion=0  
core.filemode=false  
core.bare=false  
core.logallrefupdates=true  
core.ignorecase=true  
remote.origin.url=git@git.somedomain.com:myproject/myproject.git  
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*  
branch.master.remote=origin  
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add your cygwin bin directory (probably `C:\cygwin64\bin`) to the Windows PATH environment variable. Set `C:\cygwin64\bin\git.exe` as your path to git in intellij.

Comment: I am not sure why but somehow git started to work from intelij. What you have proposed I have already been done.